# What if static electromagnetic field is turned off? (in vacuum)

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, estimation

Lets assume that there is static electromagnetic field that has $E=17mc^2$ and $p=8mc$.
At some time $t=t_0$, the field is turned off. (e.g. the electric current of coil went to zero by resistance, and the capacitor is fully discharged.) As a result, electromagnetic wave (a.k.a light) will be emitted. If we gather these waves and conduct a single mass, what will be its rest mass and its velocity? At first, I thought that energy and momentum is conserved, so that the rest mass will be $15m$, and its velocity will be $v=\frac{8}{17}c$. But after that, I saw the paper about the "hidden momentum". So I couldn't assure that my calculation is correct. So I have two questions.

1. What is the rest mass and velocity in this situation?
2. How did you derived the answer? Can I have a generalized formula of this problem?

Comment: What is “the paper”?

Comment: *Lets assume that there is static electromagnetic field that has $E=17mc^2$ and $p=8mc$.* This is not a reasonable assumption.

Comment: https://www.ate.uni-duisburg-essen.de/data/postgraduate_lecture/AJP_2009_Griffiths.pdf

Comment: This is the paper what i saw. If you have a problem to see the file, please let me know.

Comment: May I ask why the assumption isn't reasonable?

Comment: You didn’t say what $m$ is, but I assume it’s the mass of an electron. I am not aware of experimentalists ever creating electrons and positrons from *static* EM fields. This is not because you can’t store an electron’s worth of energy in such a field, but because the energy isn’t sufficiently localized to convert to an electron. You need, say, gamma ray photons, which don’t correspond to static fields.

Comment: Oh. I didn't mention what m is. Sorry about that. In the question, m means just mass. I mean, you can put any values in m except the negative value. And yes, static EM fields are 'static', so it can't create a particle such as electron and positron. But as I mentioned in the question, static field is only a initial condition. In the question, the fields are 'turned off'. The field changes eventually. So the photons can be emitted and particle can be created.

Comment: As far as I know, experimentalists have never created any particles other than photons by turning off a static EM field. And the paper does not seem to mention particle production. Did I miss it?

Comment: well, if the field is "turned off", then the interesting region you are concerned with is what might or might not happen after the power is cutoff. Localization in time of your cutoff shape will be limited by the self-capacitances and inductances of your circuit that will make your transients converge very slowly to your desired Heaviside shape. Localization in space is limited by what @G.Smith explained: lightest charged mass is the electron, which requires 511 keV gamma photons at bare minimum

Answer (score 0):

I finally understand the paper I mentioned. Even static EM field can have momentum, but if the system is 'static', the total momentum of the system will be zero. So all of the calculation and assuming was wrong. Thanks for all respondents.